# What is way we can use $ionicpopup with controllers with service authentication?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication, ionic-framework

Current Controller:

```
.controller('RegisterCtrl', function($scope, Authentication, $ionicPopup) {

      $scope.user = {};

      $scope.login = function() {
        Authentication.login($scope.user)
      };

      $scope.logout = function() {
        Authentication.logout();
      };

      $scope.register = function() {
        Authentication.register($scope.user);
      }; //register


})
```

I have tried this on one of the $scopes:

```
.controller('RegisterCtrl', function($scope, Authentication, $ionicPopup) {

      $scope.user = {};

      $scope.login = function() {
    Authentication.login($scope.user).error(function(user) {
      var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
        title: 'Login failed!',
        template: 'Please check your credentials',
        okType: 'button-assertive' // Appears red to inidicate error
      });
    });
  };

      $scope.logout = function() {
        Authentication.logout();
      };

      $scope.register = function() {
        Authentication.register($scope.user);
      }; //register


})
```

However when I try to use this instead it gives me this message auth/argument-error in the console. I have taken a look around on the ionicpopup documentation and the .then documentation to see if this can be done any differently.

I have also taken some time to read this documentation on possible reasons https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Error. I am finding it hard to understand why the error message is given to the console and not actually touching my program. Even when .error used given or alternatively .then is used I am still being given these messages although the IonicPopup is not working?? (sorry for any typos have not slept in 32 hours)

PREPARED TO ADD MORE CODE**

Comment: Please add a simple plunker

Comment: you've got a `.error()` handler on `Authenticator.login()`, but there's no `.then()` handler. Not sure if that's your issue, but it might be worth throwing one into place and see what comes back.